# ng tags not working in internet explorer

Tags: angularjs, internet-explorer, ng-tags-input

I have an angular app that works fine on all browsers except IE. Specifically the NGTAGS directive. I am unable to use ENTER or the COMMA to create an tag. There is no bugs in the console and I am not sure how to fix this.

Comment: Its running on Internet Explorer 9-11

Comment: It doesn't work in any version of IE?

Comment: I havent tested in them all but its ie 9-11 that I have tested. Please not I have testing this using an VPN with an actual version of the browser and not an emulator or setting the version in the browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might not be the answer you want, but if it isn't really necessary just ignore IE, Its been 2 years since I last developed - consciously supporting IE. 
Most of my developer-friends do the same.

The cost(in time) / benefits for being IE compatible isn't worth it.

Comment: I wish I could. Its working fine when I run it in my local IE, but I think the clients running an 'OLD' ie 10-11. if I had my way I would do a modal; that prevents old browsers from using the system but I am not eh client.

Comment: In the meantime before someone provides a real solution, you might want to look at this link towards the middle of the page : https://www.ng-book.com/p/AngularJS-and-Internet-Explorer/

I think a polyfill might be what you require.